# Use wiredep to inject custom CSS

Tags: css, gulp, wiredep

I need to inject custom CSS files everytime they are created after being compiled by gulp-less. So I tried to use wiredep with custom configurations, but without success.
I changed the tag from 'bower:css' to 'custom:css', specifically to my custom task. The bower:css for default wiredep injection is still there. But after run `myinjection` task nothing is injected even running the task without errors.
Another weird thing, when I run my task, the files injected by wiredep (the default) disappear.
What I'm missing?

Basicaly my files structure is like this:

```
|---app 
    |---styles
        |---***
        *.css
    *.html
    .custom.json
```

I'm not sure if I really need a file similar to bower.json, but I made may own custom.json

```
{
  "name": "custom",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": [
    "app/styles/**/*.css",
    "app/scripts/**/*.js //pretend to inject custom js later
  ]
}
```

The task in gulpfile.js is like this:

```
    gulp.task('myinject', function () {
    var myinject = require('wiredep').stream;

    var combined = Combine (
        gulp.src('app/*.html'),
        myinject({
            directory: 'app',
            bowerJson: require('./custom.json'),
            dependencies: false,
            html: 
            {
              block: /(([ \t]*)<!--\s*custom:*(\S*)\s*-->)(\n|\r|.)*?(<!--\s*endcustom\s*-->)/gi,
              detect: {
                js: /<script.*src=['"](.+)['"]>/gi,
                css: /<link.*href=['"](.+)['"]/gi
              },
              replace: {
                js: '<script src="{{filePath}}"></script>',
                css: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{filePath}}" />'
              }
            }
        }),
        gulp.dest('app')
    );
    combined.on('error', function(err) {
        console.warn(err.message);
    });

    return combined;
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue that I resolved with **[gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-inject)** rather than *wiredep*. 
Wiredep works fine with me when I need to include a third-party dependency (e.g. a bower package with a valid main file declared in the bower.json or a file with the same name as the directory).
However, when you want to include only a specific file (e.g. only the main.css of html5-boilerplate) **gulp-inject** is much simpler. Here is an extract of the doc :

```
gulp.task('index', function () {
  var target = gulp.src('./src/index.html');
  var sources = gulp.src(['./src/**/*.js', './src/**/*.css'], {read: false});

   return target.pipe(inject(sources))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src'));
});
```